# UISearchDisplayController with 2 fields

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a `UISearchDisplayController` into my UITableView with multiple inputs to send as parameters for the web service. Currently I think it only needs to be as simple as an extra field for entering in another variable (a lot like the one in the "Yell" app, in fact, replicating the functionality in that app is exactly what I'm after) but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. I can't find any repos on GitHub which do something similar, nor has anyone posted something similar, so does anyone have some ideas as to where to begin?

If I were to subclass UISearchDisplayController and use `- (id)initWithSearchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar contentsController:(UIViewController *)viewController` would it be possible to add an extra UISearchBar and maybe a UIButton?

Any help would be appreciated,
Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your own UIView and have multiple UISearchBar added as subviews on it with your own button and put this as your table header.

[image: You can customize your view as follows]

In your view controller you can have delegate and datasource of both the search bar as self(UIViewcontroller)

and do something like this in your delegate

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
     if(searchBar == searchBar1){
     // do your own custmization here
     }else if(searchBar = searchbar2){

     } 

     if(searchbar1.text && searchbar2.text){
        [self.tableView reloadData];
     }

}
```

In summary,
You have to create your own UIVIewcontroller which mimics (dleegate & datasource) of UISearchDisplayController

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping for something simpler than building a  custom UIViewController, but I guess this will do. Thank you.